# Padding-Top Not Working in Website

Tags: html

I am making a website for myself and I am having trouble with padding. The case I am working on involves showing a basic calculator in what ive done. The eventual goal is to have text show up upon hovering over the image, but for now the text on the image is at the top, when it needs to be in the middle.

Any comments about the code or ways to improve are greatly appreciated, and thank you very much for your help.
Also, after a little bit of research it occured to me to use the display:block, but that has not been working for me.

Thanks, Ian.

CODE:

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEEEF;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  top: 30px;
}
#text,
#text1,
#text2,
#text3 {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: none;
  color: #A4A4A4;
  padding: 0;
}
button {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}
button:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  font: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#text:hover,
#text1:hover,
#text2:hover,
#text3:hover {
  color: #EEE;
}
#text1 {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 65%;
}
#text2 {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 75%;
  top: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 15%;
}
#text3 {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 90%;
  top: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10%;
}
#AbM,
#Contact,
#CM {
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
#PW {
  background-color: #EDEEEF;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  #abtbackground-color: #EDEEEF;
}
#ABM {
  width: 60%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#CM {
  margin-left: 40%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#te {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  left: 40%;
  width: 40%;
}
#AbT,
#AbM,
#PW,
#Contact {
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  color: #2F2F2F;
}
#ABM,
#PWW,
#te {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.category {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
#ttt {
  left: 200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
#abs,
#aa {
  display: inline-block;
}
#content {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #EDEEEF;
}
#content > img {
  float: center;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 30px;
}
#c1:hover,
#c2:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  opacity: 100%;
}
#BBB:hover ~ #c1 {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
}
#BBB {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: transparent;
  top: 1375px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 36%;
  opacity: 0;
}
#B2 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
}
#onboard {
  width: 15%;
  float: center;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/2w50waa.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#onboard:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
}
#AN {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  padding-top: 1000px;
}
#cal1 {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
#BAW {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<HEAD>
  <title>Ian Winson</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!-- <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.png"> -->

  <!-- ****** faviconit.com favicons ****** -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="/favicon-192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="/favicon-160.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="/favicon-64.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon-57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/favicon-114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicon-72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/favicon-144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicon-60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/favicon-120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicon-76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/favicon-152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon-180.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicon-144.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/browserconfig.xml">
  <!-- ****** faviconit.com favicons ****** -->

</HEAD>

<body>


  <header style="overflow:hidden; margin:0">

    <div id="container">
      <center>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/p7jCsXM.jpg" width="100%"></img>
      </center>
      <font color="#2F2F2F" size="5"><button id="text" align="right" onClick="document.getElementById('ABT').scrollIntoView();" > ABOUT THIS WEBSITE</button>
            <button id="text1" align="right" onClick="document.getElementById('ABM').scrollIntoView();"> ABOUT ME</button>
            <button id="text2" align="right" onClick="document.getElementById('PW').scrollIntoView();">PROGRAMMING WORK</button>
            <button id="text3" align="right" onClick="document.getElementById('Contact').scrollIntoView();">CONTACT</button>
            </font>
    </div>
  </header>

  <center>
    <div id="AbT">
      <font color="#2F2F2F" face="Garamond">
            <br><br>

          <h1>About This Website</h1>

          <div id="ABM">
          </font>
      <font face="Open Sans">
          <p>This Website was started in Early March 2016, and I intend for it to be my platform to post updates,
            recent coding projects, resumes, and more. I am self taught in HTML, so my apologies if there are
            any bugs
           </p>
           <br><br>
         </font>

    </div>
    </div>
  </center>


  <center>
    <div id="AbM" background-colo="pink">
      <font color="#2F2F2F" face="Garamond">
            <br><br>

          <h1>About Me</h1>
          <div id="ABM">
          </font>
      <font face="Open Sans">
          <p>I'm a sophomore at Jesuit College Preperatory School in Dallas Texas(As of Early 2016).
            I have been programming for ~2 years, and mainly know Java. I have made a few apps for android, none of which have been released.
             I also have done some work programming for my FTC Robotics team, 9157. I am also a member of FRC team 2848.
           </p>
           <br><br>
         </font>

    </div>

  </center>
  <center>
    <div id="PW">
      <font color="#2F2F2F" face="Garamond">
          <h1>Programming Work</h1>
          <div id="PWW">
            <font face="Open Sans">
          <p>As previously mentioned, I mainly know Java, and this is my first big project in HTML.
              I have made Java apps including:<br>

          </div>
              <div id="content">
                <div id="onboard">
                  <div id="Cal1" <p id="AN">Basic</p><button id="AK"> Learn More</button>
                  </div>
                </div>




   <img id = "c2" src="http://oi68.tinypic.com/aax9vo.jpg" alt="" width="20%" />
   <div id = "QQQ">
   <p id = "Q1" style="padding-top: 150px;">Advanced Calculator</p>
   <p id = "Q2"> Learn More</p>
</div>


</div>

</div>
      </center>
        </font>
      <center>
        <div id="Contact">
          <font color="#2F2F2F" face="Garamond">
              <br><br>

            <h1>Contact Me</h1>
            <div id="ABM">
            </font>
          <font face="Open Sans">

            <p>If you are looking to contact me, please do it through the provided links below.<br>

              <b>Questions</b><br>
            Email: <a href="iankwinson@gmail.com">iankwinson@gmail.com</a><br>
            <b>Social Media:</b><br>
             Instagram: <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ianwinz/" >@ianwinz</a><br>
            Twitter: <a href="https://twitter.com/ianwinz">@ianwinz</a>

            </div>

             </p>
             <br><br>
           </font>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS:

```css
#AK {
  padding-top: 150px;
  }
```

It seems like the ID you are using for your button is #AK and there is no styling for that in your current CSS code. Try to manipulate the 100px (+/-) to match your needs of where you want it to be.

https://jsfiddle.net/8a0q2o0e/#&togetherjs=CN62LLHwxA

Comment: Thank You, but this only moves half of the text. There is also text thats says "basic" that will not come down.

Comment: Treat the basic part as a button, something like this:

              <div id="content">
                <div id="onboard">
                    <button id="Cal1">
                     <p id="AN">Basic</p>
                    </button>
                    <button id="AK"> Learn More</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `absolute` position on your button place this at the bottom of your css

```
#onboard{
  position: relative; /** Container to make sure position absolute stays in place **/
}
#ak{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
```